# DynamoDB: Fetch all items that match one of possible keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

Say I have the following table —

```
itemA | itemB | relationScore | type
----------------------------------------
"s"   |   "a" |      1.0      |  "foo"
"s"   |   "b" |      1.0      |  "bar"
...
```

Here, `itemA` + `itemB` is unique per row, and I've made them the hash key and range key respectively.

My query, however, needs me to fetch all items such that —

1. `itemA` is equal to one of (A,B,C,D ....) (i.e. a list of options)
2. `type` is equal to "foo"

How do I build indexes to be able to do this without using scans / requiring multiple queries?

**Note**: I don't want to query on just `type` and filter it later in memory because `type` has very low cardinality, and would end up returning a humongous list back.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

If you created a GSI with
hash key: type
range key: itemA

Then you could query using the GSI and (type = "foo", itemA between "A" and "D")

But obviously that requires itemA values to be a contiguous range.  Which seems to be the case for your example, but may not be the case for the actual data.

**EDIT**
Since the itemA values aren't actually contiguous, and DDB doesn't support `IN` you're stuck with multiple queries.

This isn't the end of the world,  as you could do the queries in parallel.  In that case, I'd probably have the GSI with
hash key: itemA
range key: type

thus ensuring that each query is partition specific.  (Even if your data or I/O requires are low enough that DDB doesn't actually create individual partitions)

Comment: Yeah, its was just for an example. Its not really a contagious range.

Comment: DDB doesn't support an `IN` operation...so you're stuck with multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

For your first access pattern, DynamoDB provides a [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) operation which can return up to 16MB of data and contain as much as 100 items.

Your second access pattern can be accessed by creating a secondary index on the `type` field.  This index would logically group all items of the same `type` into the same partition, which you could retrieve with a single `query` operation.

Edit: I misinterpreted the question and thought we were discussing two separate access patterns, not a single access pattern.  As described, the existing data model won't support a single query operation.

The only way to search across partition keys (condition 1) is by a `scan` operation, or multiple queries.  If you want to do this in a single query, you'll need to store your data such that the list of options and type is grouped together in a single partition.  This is effectively "pre joining" your data.

Unless we can exploit features of your data that are not obvious via your example (e.g. itemA is lexicographically sortable), you are going to be stuck with multiple queries or a scan operation.

Comment: My goal for the second access pattern is to query by both `itemA` and `type`. Querying by just `type` is going to give me back a very large list of results in my case which would end up eating RCUs

Comment: If that's the case, build the secondary index on a field that concatenates the two attributes.  You could create a field called itemA_type and set it the concatenated fields (e.g. "s_foo", "s_bar",etc).  If you create the secondary index on the itemA_type attribute, you could fetch by both at the same time.

Comment: would still need multiple queries

Comment: I just realized that 1 and 2 are describing the same access pattern, not 2 separate access patterns. In that case, yes, this data model is stuck with multiple queries.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.